# Prevent an element to rotate itself in a circular CSS3 animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok so this is really getting frustrated for me here, first of all if my question framing is wrong please do edit it(if you think so)...and ok, as my screens will explain you, but still I would like that my element should stay in a specific shape and not to rotate along with the animation, am missing something really stupid thing?

**What I Want** :

[image: What I Want]

**What's Happening** :

[image: What's Happening]

*jQuery Solutions Are Welcomed (But I Would Love CSS3 Solutions)*

> Note: Don't go on the element's opacity, 1 is made using Paint and
>   other with Photoshop, What Matter's Is Square Should Rotate As Square
>   Shape

HTML

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes round_round {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: round_round 3s linear infinite;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 150px;
    background-color: #8FC1E0;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background: #c00000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7Bsn/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Position it absolutely, don't change the `transform-origin`, leave it at `50% 50%`.

Then simply rotate the element, translate it by the value of the radius and then cancel the first rotation - you can see how chaining transforms works [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/3866686).

```
@keyframes rot {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translate(150px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4389712)

Comment: Now that works, Awesome...btw just be sure you add a fiddle in your answer (http://jsfiddle.net/s7Bsn/3/), and btw no need for `absolute`

Answer (score 2):

I've just written a pure JavaScript implementation for those who do not want to use CSS 3 animations (e.g. for compatibility reasons).

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQSU4/2/)

```
// requestAnim shim layer by Paul Irish
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

function CircleAnimater(elem, radius, speed) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.origX = this.elem.offsetLeft;
    this.origY = this.elem.offsetTop;
    
    this.shouldStop = false;
    this.lastFrame = 0;
    this.speed = speed;
}

CircleAnimater.prototype.start = function () {
    this.lastFrame = +new Date;
    this.shouldStop = false;
    this.animate();
}
    
CircleAnimater.prototype.stop = function () {
    this.shouldStop = true;
}
    
CircleAnimater.prototype.animate = function () {
    var now    = +new Date,
        deltaT = now - this.lastFrame;
    
    var newY = Math.sin(this.angle) * this.radius;
    var newX = Math.cos(this.angle) * this.radius;

    this.elem.style.left = (this.origX + newX) + "px";
    this.elem.style.top = (this.origY + newY) + "px";
    this.angle += (this.speed * deltaT);

    this.lastFrame = +new Date;

    if (!this.shouldStop) {
        var $this = this;
        requestAnimFrame(function () {
            $this.animate();
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: All modern browsers support CSS3 transforms (and IE since 9) - http://caniuse.com/transforms2d. Support for RAF is worse (you supplied a fallback though): http://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe

Comment: @RobW I've only written that because I kind of liked that animation.  It was just for fun. Of course, I know that CSS (3) things are always more elegant that solutions implemented in JS ;)