# Jquery - Make images rotate rotate around a center point

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation

I'm trying to do an animation where I have like 8 icons are rotating around a center point. 
I did the CSS rotate animation but it's not what I want because the images end up upside down and not pointing up. See image
[image]

I need to find a way of having the icons rotate around the center point but remain pointing upwards. 
Does anybody know how to do it or of a plugin to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Denis

Comment: Can you prepare a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: This might be exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057780/prevent-an-element-to-rotate-itself-in-a-circular-css3-animation?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created exactly this (in pure javascript though) for a client a few months ago

The trick is to rotate the small circles (the images themselves) in the reverse direction as the large circle (the path of each)

I also use an attribute called `data-angle` to give and change it it's location along the big circle, e.g. `<div class="circle one" data-angle=270>1</div>`

```
var circleArray = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
var angle = 0;

chargearray();

function chargearray () {
    for (var i = 0, j = circleArray.length; i < j; i++) {
        var circle = circleArray[i];
        var circleAngle = parseInt (circle.dataset.angle);
        var totalAngle = angle + circleAngle
        var style = "rotate(" + totalAngle + "deg) translate(200px)";
        totalAngle = - totalAngle;
        style = style + " rotate(" + totalAngle + "deg)"
        circle.style.webkitTransform = style;
        circle.style.Transform = style;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            angle = angle + 30;
            chargearray ();
            break;
        case 39:
            angle = angle - 30;
            chargearray ();
            break;
    }
}
```

[**Here is the production version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jGAze/26/)

[**Here is a more basic version of it**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jGAze/21/)

[**Here is an absolute bare-bones version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/BWV3d/1/)

The primary form of built in navigation in the final product is the buttons to answer questions, but users can also navigate using the left or right arrows (this is how the basic version works).

Adding click to navigate would be a simple task as well, simply changing `angle` to the degree of the element you want and running `changearray`

Answer (score 3):

It would require some coding, but you could animate an angle from 0.0 to 2*PI and then calculate the positions of the icons based on the angle.

```
var x = dist * cos(angle);
var y = dist * sin(angle);
```