# anchor tag doesn't work on an img in a animated div

Tags: html, css

So i'm working on a kind of solar system page. what i try to do is when a person clicks on a planet it redirects them to page. But for some reason it doesn't work. It's like the anchor doesn't exist. i tried to animate the anchor tag with the image but that doesn't seem to work.

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body>
<!-- content to be placed inside <body>…</body> -->
<div id="one"><a id="aone" href="http://google.com"><img src="one.png"></a></div>
<div id="two"><img src="two.png"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

THE CSS

```
body{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -150px;
  border: dashed 1px;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
}

#one {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -25px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  animation: rot1 8s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rot1 8s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot1 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(300px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes rot1 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translate(300px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}



#two {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -25px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
          transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
  animation: rot2 34s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rot2 34s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot2 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(150px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes rot2 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translate(150px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

#three {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -25px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%), 
    rgba(0,0,255,.3) linear-gradient(90deg, 
          transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
  animation: rot3 34s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rot3 34s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot3 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(50px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes rot3 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(50px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DJsU9/

Comment: put up a fiddle reproducing the error and someone will take a look...

Comment: The issue happens because the CSS `transform` property isn't moving the `a` element. If you move the mouse over the first `#one`'s position you'll see that the mouse change to pointer.

Comment: how can i move it then?

Comment: I don't know if you **can** move it, I think that the `transform` property may only move the element's graphic, but not the real position. You can use javascript as workaround here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to move the real anchor position (not just the graphics position) using the CSS `transform` property but there's an incredibly easy solution for this question without the use of javascript:

You can create three invisible circles, put links on each one and then position them over the existing animation. This method is good because even if the user clicks in the wrong position the link will work.

Note that I've colored the circles with transparent red, but you can (and should) remove the color by deleting the `background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);` lines.

**Here's the relevant CSS:**

```
.circle1{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-325px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-325px;
    width:650px;
    height:650px;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5); /* unnecessary */
    border-radius:100%;
}
.circle2{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-175px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-175px;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5); /* unnecessary */
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="one"><a id="aone" href="http://google.com"><img src="http://dedobbelaere.sisamul.com/one.png"></a>
</div>
<div id="two"><a id="aone" href="http://google.com"><img src="http://dedobbelaere.sisamul.com/two.png"></a>
</div>
<div id="three"></div>

<a class="circle1" href="http://dedobbelaere.sisamul.com/two.png"></div>
<a class="circle2" href="http://google.com"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/DJsU9/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Only corrected sintax on nested html element, tested on IE10 and Chrome35(Windows 8 Pro), but probably you need to fix some platform/cross-browser issue.
Anyway you should set an unique id to your hyperlinks

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/DJsU9/11/

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
 <a id="aone" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://dedobbelaere.sisamul.com/one.png"/>
 </a>
</div>
<div id="two">
 <a id="aone" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://dedobbelaere.sisamul.com/two.png"/>
 </a>
</div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/**
 * Prevent an element to rotate itself in a circular CSS3 animation
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/14057780/1397351
 */
 a {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px;
    border: dashed 1px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content:'';
}
#one {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: rot1 8s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot1 8s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(300px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(300px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rot1 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(300px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translate(300px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
#two {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
    animation: rot2 34s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot2 34s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(150px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(150px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rot2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(150px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translate(300px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
#three {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%), rgba(0, 0, 255, .3) linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
    animation: rot3 34s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot3 34s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(50px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rot3 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translate(50px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working properly on Mac OS Safari 7.0.4. The link seems to disappear randomly during rotation.